# delete empty blocks with nesting

Tags: text-processing, sed

I want to delete empty config blocks of the form (with nesting also)

Input File:

```
abc {
a
}
bcd {
    spq {
    }
}
ecd pqr {
}
xyz {
so
}
```

Expected Output:

```
abc {
a
}
xyz {
so
}
```

I tried:

```
sed '/{$/{N;/{\n\s}$/d}' SampleToDelete.txt
```

but this does not help. New line and white spaces I am unable to represent.

Comment: How big is the file? Is it small enough to be loaded into memory or is it several GB in size?

Comment: 2 to 3 MB maximum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ sed -n -f script.sed file
abc {
a
}
xyz {
so
}
```

Where `script.sed` is

```
1 {
    # 1st line, save it to the hold space
    # and skip to next line.
    h
    d
}

# Append all other lines to hold space
# with an embedded newline as delimiter.
H

$ {
    # Last line, swap in hold space
    # (which by now contains the whole document).
    x

    # Replace all empty "word { ... }" sections
    # until there are no more such sections.
    # "word" may be a single word or multiple words
    # separated by whitespace.

    :again
    s/[[:alnum:][:space:]]*[[:space:]]*{[[:space:]]*}//g
    t again

    # Squeeze multiple newlines into single newlines.
    s/\(\n\)\1*/\1/g

    # Output.
    p
}
```

The `[[:space:]]` pattern matches blanks and newlines (and a few other space-like characters).

The pattern `[[:alnum:][:space:]]*[[:space:]]*{[[:space:]]*}` would match one of your `word { ... }` sections where the `{ ... }` is empty or contains only space characters (spaces, tabs, newlines etc.) and where `word` may be a single word or multiple words separated by whitespace.  It would also match an "anonymous" empty section, such as `{ }` (no `word` label in front of it).

Empty sections are removed in a loop (the `again` label in the code).  The `t` command will branch to the given label if the most recent `s` command made at least one substitution.  If it did, there may now be further empty sections to remove, hence the loop.

For data such as

```
a { b { c { d { e { } } } } }
```

that loop would run the `s` command five times (eventually deleting everything).

---

Your `sed` script:

```
/{$/{N;/{\n\s}$/d}
```

or, in long form,

```
/{$/ {
    N
    /{\n\s}$/d
}
```

would never be able to delete sections that contain empty sections, as in `a { b { } }`. Also, it seems to ignore the section label and the possibility that a section may look like `a { b { } abc c { d { } } }` (which would be removed completely if it was split into two lines, rather than transformed into `a { abc }`).

Also, I'm uncertain what `\s` is matching, but it seems to match the same as `[[:space:]]` with GNU `sed`.  Standard `sed` requires a newline or `;` at the end of commands, so the script would have to have `d;}` at the end (in the one-line version).

Comment: abc {
     a
     }
     bcd {
   spq {
   }
      }
      ecd ijk {
      }
      xyz {
      so
      }
For the above file(with space in text followed by {) , I changed to s/[[:alnum:]]*[[:space:]]*[[:alnum:]]*[[:space:]]*{[[:space:]]*}//g but I get                                                               abc {
     a
     }
     ecd 
     xyz {
     so
     }  I expect abc {
     a
     }     
     xyz {
     so
     }

Comment: Edited the question with this requirement.

Comment: @itsraja Updated answer.